# Unable to add SQL server and Java script component in logicapp

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am using Consumption Logic App for which I want to add SQL Server Component and Java Script component. I am unable to that.

[image]

Here is the workflow created and unable to find required components

Comment: It looks like you typed **SOL server** ... what about the Javascript action, can you show an image what you searched for there?

Comment: I’d raise it with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you can** achieve adding SQL server component or java script component using Consumption Logic app
[image]
[image].

**However, you can achieve it using Standard Logic app also.**
[image]
[image]

Please refer the following [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare)

Comment: Sorry, but this isn’t correct. I’ve been using consumption forever and I can see those two connectors. There has to be another reason.